# Cannot access the parameters passed from python render_template (jinja2 / webapp2) on html javascript

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, jinja2, webapp2

I am trying to send parameters to a URL that was generated in my server (python) code. This URL will be sent to a user via email. I am using the Google App Engine to host my entire application.

```
class VerificationHandler(basehandler.BaseHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        params = {
            'user': user,
            'token': signup_token
            }
        self.render_template('some_url_to_click.html', params)
```

In my some_url_to_click.html, I have the following code. The framework that I am using is Jinja2.

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% block maincontent %}


<div id="text_display_div">

    <br></br>
    <a>Enter Text.</a>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var param_from_backend = '{{ params}}'
    alert (param_from_backend.user)
 });

</script>
```

I am not able to access the params variable in my javascript. I get "undefined" error on param_from_backend.user

Answer (score 1):

You have to access each variable individually in JS. This will solve your problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var user = '{{ params.user }}';
    var token= '{{ params.signup_token}}';
    alert (user + " " + token);
 });    
</script>
```